# Adding spaces to words separated by punctuation marks but not delimited properly

Tags: php

I have bio information inside a variable:

**$bio = 'text, text, text...';**

I trim that text and use rtrim php function at the end

```
trim($bio);
rtrim($bio,',.;:- _!$&#');
```

The problem is that sometimes the bio information has a structure like this:

```
$bio = 'hello, i am jason!and i like cars,sports,beer and boats, tv, papers.';
```

**Is there a way to add spaces when two words separated by punctuation marks are not delimited by spaces? Like "i am jason!and" or "cars,sports,beer"**

$bio should be:

```
$bio = 'hello, i am jason and i like cars, sports, beer and boats, tv, papers.';
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always have a loop that checks each index of the string, and if it equals one of the given punctuations you have, create a new string such as

```
$bio = substr($bio,0,index of punctuation+1)." ".substr($bio,index of punctuation+1,length     of bio);
```

It's bulky for sure but should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace occurrences of  punctuation mark followed by alpha(numeric?) literal (without white space inbetween) to be replaced by the same punctuation symbol followed by a white space and the rest :)

Comment: Sound like the way to do it, I am a total newb... could you give me an example? I have no idea how to write the preg replace regex. Ty